# Flask Run Function on button click

Tags: python, flask

I am looking to make a web page to enable triggering few processes on network. I have decided to use flask as the research i did online overwhelming suggest flask being better for beginners.

I have written the following code as a sample and to test my knowledge. I want to trigger a process on button click. However it doesn't seem to render the next page on click. Any help would be appreciated.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import testt
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')
@app.route('/my-link/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def my_link():
    testt.trial()
    work  = 'working'
    return render_template('process-complete.html',work= work)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

process-complete.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>Task Master</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="content" method= "post">
    <h1 style="text-align: center">Flask Trial</h1>    
    <div class="form">
        <p> Process Completed {{work}}.<p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You don't have a form that has an `action` pointing to an endpoint. Forms would be overkill anyway, you just need `<a class="button" href="{{ url_for('my_link') }}">Flask Trial</a>`. But a full answer is going to have to cover a lot of ground. You'd be better following a tutorial

Comment: 1) share index.html 2) add s print as the first line of my_link function. Do you see the print on the server side?

Comment: @roganjosh that works for my purpose at the moment Thank you. i think i will have a quite a bit of reading before i get anything more advanced. Any pointers ?

Comment: [The Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) will get you running with Flask. This is more front-end stuff, so it's not as focused on HTML and JS, but it's a good resource in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below helped me execute the action i wanted to perform.

```html
<p>Click Below to Start the Process<p>
<a class="button" href="{{ url_for('my_link') }}">Flask Trial</a>
```